# vue-filepond and array from v-for [v-model]?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

```
 <div v-for="(input, index) in portfolio"
                ref="mPort"
                :key="`portfolio-${index}`"
                class="pb-4"
              >
                <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4">
                  <div>
                    <file-pond
                      name="userPorfolio"
                      ref="portfolio"
                      accepted-file-types="image/jpeg, image/png"
                      allow-multiple="true"
                      instantUpload="true"
                      max-files="1"
                      class="h-full"
                      v-model="input.photo"
                      :server="{ process, revert, restore, load, fetch }"
                    />
                  </div>
</div>
```

code from method input.photo empty

I'm trying make array from component file-pond but this not working how make it?

Comment: you can define a array variable `photos: []` in your data object and then you can just use `v-model="photos"`. At the end it will give you an array of all the photos.